# MSMQ - Multiple Subscribers and Event Notification

Tags: msmq

I'm a bit new to MSMQ and need a bit of help. We have a JMS based messaging system and we are considering replacing it with MSMQ. There are 2 existing scenarios in JMS which i need to verify MSMQ supports.

1. Multiple Subscriber Applications for the same message.
2. Notification send to a Subscriber Application that a message has arrived for them. (Basically MSMQ pushing message to the subscriber application as opposed to the Subscriber application checking the Queue in MSMQ)

If anyone could provide any info or link to any sites with the relevant info, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks,

Tarique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Multiple Subscriber Applications for the same message.

You can do this with [Multiple-Destination Messaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706929%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Notification send to a Subscriber Application that a message has arrived for them.

Use async pattern for this, you begin listen for a message and get notification when it arrives (C# method, such as `MyReceiveCompleted` in the code sample). From personal experience this works slower than reading one by one in a sync way. But if you handle less than 1k messages a second on an arbitary average machine you will be fine.

See [MessageQueue.BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0syd8kf.aspx) for code sample.